# Sort order of an SQL Server 2008+ clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, clustered-index

Does the sort order of a SQL Server 2008+ clustered index impact the insert performance?

The datatype in the specific case is `integer` and the inserted values are ascending (`Identity`). Therefore, the sort order of the index would be opposite to the sort order of the values to be inserted.

My guess is, that it will have an impact, but I don’t know, maybe SQL Server has some optimizations for this case or it’s internal data storage format is indifferent to this.

Please note that the question is about the `INSERT` performance, not `SELECT`.

**Update**
To be more clear about the question: What happens when the values which will be inserted (`integer`) are in reverse order (`ASC`) to the ordering of the clustered index (`DESC`)?

Comment: Why do you say that "_the sort order of the index would be opposite to the sort order of the values to be inserted_"? Is it to be assumed that the Clustered Index was declared as `DESC`? If not, the default is `ASC`, which is the _same_ order as the values to be inserted. I could be misreading something, however.

Comment: This is the core of the question: What happens when the identity-value counts up but the sort order was set manually to desc. Probably I have not made this fully clear in my post, sorry, I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: In your environment are people running SELECT statements that ORDER by the Clustered Index in descending order?

Comment: Yes, almost always when they query, but inserts are much more frequently. But besides this, I find the question also interesting from a generic view, without the scope of the concrete application.

Comment: The Clustered Index should have been ASC (to prevent Fragmentation), then an additional NonClustered index containing the ID in DESC order (to support reporting). It's a good question for highlighting how inappropriate Clustered Indexes get easily fragmented.

Comment: @pacreely - there's no need to create a `DESC` index at all. SQL Server can scan indexes backwards or forwards (though backward scans are never parallelised)

Comment: I'm not sure what the point is here - if you *need* a particular clustered index definition, then, having established you performance *goals*, test the setup using *your* workloads and see whether it's fit for purpose. If it fits your goals, use it. If it doesn't fit your goals, then obviously something will have to change, but if it's vastly under-performing, it's unlikely that a small tweak to e.g. the clustered index definition will make a difference.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Knowledge is the point here. Trial and error is sometimes tempting, knowing what happens however is IMO preferable. And the answer which was posted by pacreely helped me a lot to understand what happens. Without investing a lot of time, I would not have gained this insight.

Comment: Thanks, glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference. Inserting out of Cluster Order causes massive fragmentation.

When you run the following code the DESC clustered index is generating additional UPDATE operations at the NONLEAF level.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TEST_ASC(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) 
                            ,RandNo FLOAT
                            );
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cidx ON dbo.TEST_ASC(ID ASC);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TEST_DESC(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) 
                            ,RandNo FLOAT
                            );
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cidx ON dbo.TEST_DESC(ID DESC);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_ASC VALUES(RAND());
GO 100000

INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_DESC VALUES(RAND());
GO 100000
```

The two Insert statements produce exactly the same Execution Plan but when looking at the operational stats the differences show up against [nonleaf_update_count].

```
SELECT 
OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
,* 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(DB_ID(),OBJECT_ID('TEST_ASC'),null,null)
UNION
SELECT 
OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
,* 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(DB_ID(),OBJECT_ID('TEST_DESC'),null,null)
```

There is an extra –under the hood- operation going on when SQL is working with DESC index that runs against the IDENTITY.
This is because the DESC table is becoming fragmented (rows inserted at the start of the page) and additional updates occur to maintain the B-tree structure.

The most noticeable thing about this example is that the DESC Clustered Index becomes over 99% fragmented. [This is recreating the same bad behaviour as using a random GUID for a clustered index.](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/clustered-indexes-based-upon-guids)
The below code demonstrates the fragmentation.

```
SELECT 
OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
,* 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats  (DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('dbo.TEST_ASC'), NULL, NULL ,NULL) 
UNION
SELECT 
OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
,* 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats  (DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('dbo.TEST_DESC'), NULL, NULL ,NULL)
```

**UPDATE:**

On some test environments I'm also seeing that the DESC table is subject to more WAITS with an increase in [page_io_latch_wait_count] and [page_io_latch_wait_in_ms]

**UPDATE:**

Some discussion has arisen about what is the point of a Descending Index when SQL can perform Backward Scans. Please read this article about the [limitations of Backward Scans](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/descending-indexes).

Comment: Or it could be that SQL Server is optimizing for in-order clustered index inserts that always go into the last page of the index, and the desc insert doesn't get those optimizations.

Comment: It's normal to reorder the non leaf level, but that should be an operation done a few times (in your example 260 times for 100k inserts) in a very small collection and usually in memory as when inserting sequential the current leaf page stays in memory for a long time  .. so it has no real impact on performance.

Comment: Dumitrescu: It is normal but the difference between ASC (0) and DESC (260) can't be ignored. If this were scaled-up to a multi-terabyte production system then the difference would become noticeable.

Comment: Actually you are wrong, there is no fragmentation generated by the inserts. The only thing that occurs is that every time a new page is added to the B-TREE (leaf level) on top of the clustered index, the pages need to be reordered. For more information: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pamitt/2010/12/23/notes-sql-server-index-fragmentation-types-and-solutions/

Comment: @dumitrescu: "non sequential inserts" are what the OP was asking about. The link you've provided explains how they cause fragmentation.

Comment: The inserts are sequential, the order is the one that is reversed. Pages will feel up normally one at a time, there will be no page splits or other events to cause fragmentation. This is an absolutely normal fill up of the clustered index, with your observed difference, that once a leaf page feels up it needs to be linked in the correct place in the B-Tree, that is the only thing not happening as in a normal sequential/ ordered insert. This is actually proven by your initial stats, you only see a small difference at leaf level.

Comment: @dumitrescu: Each new record will be inserted at the beginning of the first leaf level page. After the first page has been filled this causes a new page split for every 4k of data inserted, each split requires an update to the non-leaf level.

Comment: Well .. just no, the data in a clustered index, is stored like this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443(v=sql.105).aspx . I already said that the data will not do any page splits. Neither will the B-Tree. It's only a matter of linking in the B-Tree. I explained why in my answer. Anyway, I will not continue this, so .. Just read.

Comment: @dumitrescu: "All inserts are made at the point where the key value in the inserted row fits in the ordering sequence among existing rows". the link you've provided confirms the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: Read all the links I gave, it will put it in that particular page. The order in the page is not important. It just needs to belong to the page: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-storage-internals-101/ . it will add in the page up to when the page fills up. Then go to the next and the next and so on. If you compare 2 inserts, one with page splits at every insert and one without, the difference in time for 100k is huge even for the smallest data, while in your example run several time the difference is either way counted in ms.

Comment: @dumitrescu: I'm sorry we can't agree on this. I'm not disputing your SQL knowledge, but I do think you haven't understood the OP's question. I recommend that you re-phrase the question as you understand it and post it to the Database Administrators community, you should get a lot of constructive feedback.

Answer (score 7):

The order of values inserted into a clustered index most certainly impacts performance of the index, by potentially creating a lot of fragmentation, and also affects the performance of the insert itself.

I've constructed a test-bed to see what happens:

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestSort
(
    Sorted INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_TestSort
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , SomeData VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.TestSort (Sorted, SomeData)
VALUES  (1797604285, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1530768597, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1274169954, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-1972758125, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1768931454, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-1180422587, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-1373873804, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (293442810, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-2126229859, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (715871545, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-1163940131, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (566332020, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1880249597, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-1213257849, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-155893134, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (976883931, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-1424958821, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-279093766, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-903956376, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (181119720, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-422397654, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-560438983, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (968519165, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1820871210, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-1348787729, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-1869809700, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (423340320, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (125852107, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-1690550622, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (570776311, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (2120766755, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1123596784, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (496886282, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-571192016, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1036877128, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1518056151, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1617326587, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (410892484, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1826927956, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-1898916773, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (245592851, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1826773413, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1451000899, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1234288293, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1433618321, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-1584291587, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-554159323, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (-1478814392, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (1326124163, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))
    , (701812459, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024));
```

The first column is the primary key, and as you can see the values are listed in random(ish) order.  Listing the values in random order should make SQL Server either:

1. Sort the data, *pre-insert*
2. Not sort the data, resulting in a fragmented table.

The `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()` function is used to generate 1024 bytes of random data per row, to allow this table to consume multiple pages, which in turn allows us to see the effects of fragmented inserts.

Once you run the above insert, you can check fragmentation like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('TestSort'), 1, 0, 'SAMPLED') ips;
```

Running this on my SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition instance shows average fragmentation of 90%, indicating SQL Server did not sort during the insert.

The moral of this *particular* story is likely to be, "when in doubt, sort, if it will be beneficial".  Having said that, adding and `ORDER BY` clause to an insert statement does not guarantee the inserts will occur in that order.  Consider what happens if the insert goes parallel, as an example.

On non-production systems you can use trace flag 2332 as an option on the insert statement to "force" SQL Server to sort the input prior to inserting it.  [@PaulWhite](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white) has an interesting article, [Optimizing T-SQL queries that change data](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2013/01/26/optimizing-t-sql-queries-that-change-data.aspx) covering that, and other details.  Be aware, that trace flag is unsupported, and should NOT be used in production systems, since that might void your warranty.  In a non-production system, for your own education, you can try adding this to the end of the `INSERT` statement:

```
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 2332);
```

Once you have that appended to the insert, take a look at the plan, you'll see an explicit sort:

[image]

It would be great if Microsoft would make this a supported trace flag.

[Paul White made me aware](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34605950#34605950) that SQL Server *does* automatically introduce a sort operator into the plan when it thinks one will be helpful.  For the sample query above, if I run the insert with 250 items in the `values` clause, no sort is implemented automatically.  However, at 251 items, SQL Server automatically sorts the values prior to the insert.  Why the cutoff is 250/251 rows remains a mystery to me, other than it seems to be hard-coded.  If I reduce the size of the data inserted in the `SomeData` column to just one byte, the cutoff is *still* 250/251 rows, even though the size of the table in both cases is just a single page.  Interestingly, looking at the insert with `SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;` shows the inserts with a single byte `SomeData` value take twice as long when sorted.

Without the sort (i.e. 250 rows inserted):

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 16 ms, elapsed time = 16 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'TestSort'. Scan count 0, logical reads 501, physical reads 0, 
   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob 
   read-ahead reads 0.

(250 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 11 ms.
```

With the sort (i.e. 251 rows inserted):

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 15 ms, elapsed time = 17 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'TestSort'. Scan count 0, logical reads 503, physical reads 0, 
   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob 
   read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, 
   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob 
   read-ahead reads 0.

(251 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 21 ms.
```

Once you start to increase the row size, the sorted version certainly becomes more efficient.  When inserting 4096 bytes into `SomeData`, the sorted insert is nearly twice as fast on my test rig as the unsorted insert.

---

As a side-note, in case you're interested, I generated the `VALUES (...)` clause using this T-SQL:

```
;WITH s AS (
    SELECT v.Item
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) v(Item)
)
, v AS (
    SELECT Num = CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(10), 0)
)
, o AS (
    SELECT v.Num
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.Num ORDER BY NEWID())
    FROM s s1
        CROSS JOIN s s2
        CROSS JOIN s s3
        CROSS JOIN v 
)
SELECT TOP(50) ', (' 
        + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(11), o.Num), '*', '0') 
        + ', CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1024))'
FROM o
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

This generates 1,000 random values, selecting only the top 50 rows with unique values in the first column.  I copied-and-pasted the output into the `INSERT` statement above.

Comment: Thanks for your very interesting and profound answer. However, your argumentation is based on random data, but the question is specifically about ordered data (IDENTITY). The clustered index is set to DESC and the values will count up in ascending order. Besides this, there will never be bulk-inserts, its always one record at a time that is inserted.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7372/123892 — explains why the number of rows matter. TLDR: DMLRequestSort in a query plan will ensure an internal sort is done (if needed) and thus avoids the bad fragmentation. This is also applies to Minimal Logging scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data comes ordered by the clustered index (irrespective if it's ascending or descending), then there should not be any impact on the insert performance. The reasoning behind this is that SQL does not care of the physical order of the rows in a page for the clustered index. The order of the rows is kept in what is called a "Record Offset Array", which is the only one that needs to be rewritten for a new row (which anyway would have been done irrespective of order). The actual data rows will just get written one after the other.

At transaction log level, the entries should be identical irrespective of the direction so this will not generate any additional impact on performance. Usually the transaction log is the one that generates most of the performance issues, but in this case there will be none.

You can find a good explanation on the physical structure of a page / row here https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-storage-internals-101/ .

So basically as long as your inserts will not generate page splits (and if the data comes in the order of the clustered index irrespective of order it will not), your inserts will have negligible if any impact on the insert performance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code below, inserting data into an identity column with a sorted clustered index is more resource intense when the selected data is ordered in the opposite direction of the sorted clustered index.

In this example, logical reads are nearly double.

After 10 runs, the sorted ascending logical reads average 2284 and the sorted descending logical reads average 4301.

```
--Drop Table Destination;
Create Table Destination (MyId INT IDENTITY(1,1))

Create Clustered Index ClIndex On Destination(MyId ASC)

set identity_insert destination on 
Insert into Destination (MyId)
SELECT TOP (1000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
FROM sys.all_objects 
ORDER BY n


set identity_insert destination on 
Insert into Destination (MyId)
SELECT TOP (1000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
FROM sys.all_objects 
ORDER BY n desc;
```

More about logical reads if you are interested:
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/06/tsql-measure-performance-improvements/